# Chat map with react js, objects inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a basic chat.
I want that for every contact I could save the messages from the both users and show them on the screen (just like chat in whatsapp web).

My code:

```
    const [chatArr , setChatArr] = useState([
    {
        id: "v7fAa5OltrU=",
        from: "Shai Dayan",
        newMsg:{
            msgs: [
                {sender: 0, text:"Hello there, I'm using Chat !"},
             {sender: 1, text:"Hello there, I'm using Chat !"}
        ]
        },
        group: false,
        players: ['Shai Dayan']
},
```

And I'm trying to map this texts like this:

```
                    {chatArr[fullChat].newMsg.msgs.map((element,index)=>{
                    return <div className='speech-bubble'>
                        <div className="text-msg">
                            <div className='name-msg'>
                        <span className='from'>{chatArr[fullChat].from}</span> <br/>
                        {element.text}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                })}
```

but it is not working..How can I make a array of objects that each object will contain the sender and the text and map it by the order?

Comment: What is `fullChat`?

Answer (score 0):

From the array you posted here is how you can map over it.

You need to have a nested map, first to map over your chats and then to map over each message in the chat

```
{
    chatArr && chatArr.map((chat,index) => {
        return (
            <>
                {
                    chat.newMsg.msgs.map((msg,idx) => {
                        return (
                            <div className='speech-bubble'>
                                <div className="text-msg">
                                    <div className='name-msg'>
                                        <span className='from'>{chat.from}</span> 
                                        <br/>
                                        {msg.text}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
               
            </>
        )
    }
}
```